# Postgres forces use of COALESCE while the value cannot be null

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions

I am running a troubling request on Postgres and cannot figure out the following point.

Note : The following requests do not need tables, you may try them in any postgres prompt.

Given the following sample data :

```sql
SELECT
*
FROM jsonb_to_recordset('[{"cat": "A", "key": null, "value": null}, {"cat": "A", "key": "key_A", "value": "val_A"}, {"cat": "B", "key": null, "value": null}, {"cat": "C", "key": "key_C", "value": "val_C"}]')
AS x(cat text, key text, value text);
```

```
 cat |  key  | value 
-----+-------+-------
 A   |       | 
 A   | key_A | val_A
 B   |       | 
 C   | key_C | val_C
(4 rows)
```

The following query is working fine :

```sql
SELECT
cat,
CASE WHEN bool_or(key IS NULL) THEN null
ELSE
   jsonb_object_agg(COALESCE(key, '???'), value)
END AS obj
FROM jsonb_to_recordset('[{"cat": "A", "key": null, "value": null}, {"cat": "A", "key": "key_A", "value": "val_A"}, {"cat": "B", "key": null, "value": null}, {"cat": "C", "key": "key_C", "value": "val_C"}]')
AS x(cat text, key text, value text)
GROUP BY cat
```

```
 cat |        obj         
-----+--------------------
 B   | 
 C   | {"key_C": "val_C"}
 A   | 
(3 rows)
```

But I do not understand why I have to use the `COALESCE` since I guess at this point the value CANNOT be null (as you can see in the result there is no `???` key.

However, when I remove the `COALESCE` :

```sql
SELECT
cat,
CASE WHEN bool_or(key IS NULL) THEN null
ELSE
   jsonb_object_agg(key, value)
END AS obj
FROM jsonb_to_recordset('[{"cat": "A", "key": null, "value": null}, {"cat": "A", "key": "key_A", "value": "val_A"}, {"cat": "B", "key": null, "value": null}, {"cat": "C", "key": "key_C", "value": "val_C"}]')
AS x(cat text, key text, value text)
GROUP BY cat
```

```
psql:commands.sql:9: ERROR:  field name must not be null
```

I would appreciate any enlightning ! Cheers.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Really? I only see `jsonb_to_recordset`, not `->`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The aggregates are calculated for each row simultaneously. The first value for `jsonb_object_agg()` is computed when the result of `bool_or()` is not yet known. You can illustrate this mechanism with a trivial custom aggregate:

```sql
create or replace function my_agg_function(int, int)
returns int language plpgsql as $$
begin
    raise notice 'called for %', $2;
    return coalesce($1, 0)+ coalesce($2, 0);
end $$;

create aggregate my_agg(int) (
    sfunc = my_agg_function,
    stype = int);
```

In the below query `my_agg_function()` is executed three times because the result of `bool_or()` is only known when all rows are processed:

```sql
select case when bool_or(i = 10) then my_agg(i) end
from generate_series(1, 3) as i;

NOTICE:  called for 1
NOTICE:  called for 2
NOTICE:  called for 3
 case
------

(1 row)
```